# counter for shooting game

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm wondering how do I go by creating code that, when shot, will count the number of that item I have left? I'm doing a shooting gallery; nothing too special. So In more detail, I have 8 monsters that appear on screen at random, I have another graphic on the side, which holds the counter that starts at 8 (number of monsters). After shooting one the counter will go down from 8 to 7, 6, 5, 4, ...ect.

I have a Main class, which holds all the code to place the monsters on the list, a monsters class, which will only have the animation and last, another class for the board (counter) I'm not sure how to get the counter working like I want it. Anyone think they can help?

Also, the board has a dynamic text field that already says "Monster's Left" that was made in Flash and I need that to count down.

Yea, sorry, here is the code I'm using:

```
private var _monsters:Array = []; 

for(var j:uint = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    var monster:Monster = new Monster();
    this.addChild(monster);
    monster.x = 100 + j * 100;
    monster.y = 475;
    _monsters.push(monster);
    monster.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, monsterDestroy);
}
```

the code above is in the main class: below is the code for the board:

```
import flash.events.Event;

public class Board extends ScoreDisplayBase
{
    private var _monsters:Array = [];

    public function Board()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countDown);
    }

    private function countDown(event:Event):void
    {
        //store the monster we clicked on in a new array
        var clickedMonster:monster = monster(event.currentTarget);

        var index:uint = _monsters.indexOf(clickedMonster);
    }
```

Comment: do you create the monsters as objects? if you have them listed in an array you could get the array length each time the user clicks. if a monster got shot and (deleted) you decrement the size of that array by one and you've got the amount of remaining monsters.

Comment: Yea, sorry, here is the code I'm using: private var _monsters:Array = [];

Comment: and if the mouse is on a monster at "onclick" you do what?

Comment: i still haven't fully understood how to use this site when adding code, so some of it looks like normal text

Answer (score 0):

ah ok you do it that way round...

you should write an onclick-eventlistener. everytime a monster gets clicked you increase the amount of clicked monsters (and delete or remove that particular monster) and compare if the amount of clicked monsters equals the size of the array you initiated at the beginning.

Comment: ugh! i thought it would be as easy as:  this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
   
  }
  
  private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
   this.board = monster.length
  }

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could add `var alive:Boolean` to your monster class, and to check the number of live monsters you would iterate through your list and add +1 for each true. This would be more scalable, since if you added or removed monsters the number would remain accurate.

Comment: I have my everything working up until the counter. i can shoot the monsters, and everything has animation. coding the counter part feels simple, but it's not coming to me. since the text displayed on the counter board is dynamic, would i add the code inside the onClick function?